# Rational points of quotient vs. quotient of rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In general, if $G$ is an algebraic group and $H$ is a subgroup for which $G/H$ is defined, both defined over a field $k$, $G(k)/H(k)$ need not be equal to $(G/H)(k)$. This is explained here: [Quotient of group schemes and its rational points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753917/quotient-of-group-schemes-and-its-rational-points)

How would this work for $G=GL_2$ and $H=Z(G)$? Then $G/H = PGL_2$. How can I get a field $k$ for which $GL_2(k)/Z_{GL_2}(k)$ is smaller than $PGL_2(k)$?

Comment: Here, these groups are equal, indeed $H(k)\simeq k^*$ and by Hilbert 90, $H^1(G_k,H(\overline{k}))=0$.